# How to flatten Nested json in AWS Athena?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, hiveql, presto, amazon-athena

I have a JSON file like this and Want output shown below.:

[image]

Can you tell me how to query a table with an array of struct?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is rather broad, can you specify what values you are interested in. As a general approach, I would recommend the PrestoDB guide on unnesting arrays: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html

Comment: Say I want to query all ids and property distance and time. I can access property distance and time of one array element at a time. I'm looking to get all property distance and time with ID column.

Comment: try UNNEST on partner and you will get it.